# Create a CMOS circuit from a logic function F=~A+B

Tags: cmos, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I tried to draw the a CMOS logic circuit, but I don't know whether is is right or not.

The function is: \$  F = \overline{A} + B  \$

$$ F = \overline{A} + B $$

$$ \overline{F} = \overline{\overline{A} + B} \Rightarrow A \times \overline{B} $$

---

[image]

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp5Lbi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZq9i.jpg) to original paper.

Comment: The expression is \$(¬A)+B\$ or \$¬(A+B)\$?

Comment: Its (~A)+B.@OFRBG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fELSpO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please note that since the high side mos are P mosfets they are on when the input is *low*.

How did I draw that? First of all you need to fill the truth table, then you build the **pull down network**, i.e. the NMOS part, and the **pull up network** separately.

Let's make the table:

```
A    B    F
0    0    1
0    1    1
1    0    0
1    1    1
```

Inspecting the table you can see that the output is low when A=1 *and* B=0. Your pull down network will consist of two series (logical AND) transistors, one connected to A, the other to /B.

The output is high if A=0 *or* (A=1 *and* B=1). Note that here I have already simplified the formula (search for karnaugh maps, minterms, maxterms, product of sum, sum of product).

Your pull up network will consist of the parallel (logical OR) of:

- the series (AND) of two transistors, one connected to /A, the other to /B
- a single transistor connected to A

Note that i inverted the signals for the pull up network because P mos turn on when input is LOW.

Comment: sry i didn't understand the PMOS part.@Vladimir Cravero

Comment: Yeah... What about it exactly?

Comment: M5 is not really necessary, since the expression "A=0 or (A=1 and B=1)" is logically equivalent to "A=0 or B=1".

Comment: You have used three input on the PMOS side and two on NMOS side, but as much as i have studied CMOS you are required to have same number of inputs on both PMOS and NMOS side.

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi can you provide any source on this? CMOS stands for 'complementary MOS' and I do not see equal number of inputs a requirement. Think of a function that must be low when one input is high, and high when any other input is low, i.e. something like A(/B+/C+/D...). This can be implemented with one transistor on the PDN and all the others on the PUN.

Comment: @Res please note that if you omit M5, as Justin said, my circuit and yours are exactly the same.

Answer (score -2):

Its a tricky question and this must have been told to you by your tutor. I am giving away the answer here since because you have tried it.
 The truth table for this

[image]

You can see from the table that for the case A=T and B=T output is T and for A=T and B=F output is F. The transition in the value of B from T to F indicates that one of the inputs has gone low, so CMOS being a negative logic the output should either remain the same or or show a F to T transition.

In this case, F to T transition is not applicable since initial output is T , so for this circuit to be implementable with CMOS, the putput should have remained T. Hence this function can not be realized with a **SINGLE CMOS CIRCUIT**

Comment: Thankyou...but please upload the logic circuit for this...@Abhishek Tyagi

Comment: Abhi, I believe our definitions of CMOS circuit are quite different.

Comment: @VladimirCravero How come, can you please elaborate?

Comment: You say that such a circuit can't be built but I've built it just above your answer...